# Problem building prisma models with multiple relations

Tags: prisma

I am new to prisma.
And I'm stucked, because prisma required backwards relations.

I have 3 models: `Event`, `File` and `User`

The `Event` model may have multiple `File`s attached, as well as an avatar `File`.
The `Event` is created by a `User`.
The `User` may have its own avatar `File`

Here are the simplified models I've build so far.

```sql
model Event {
  id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())

  /*
     Optional: There can be several files (including image) attached to the event
     ERROR HERE:
     Error validating model "Event": Ambiguous relation detected.
     The fields `files` and `avatar` in model `Event` both refer to `File`.
     Please provide different relation names for them by adding `@relation(<name>).
  */
  files  File[] @relation(fields: [fileId], references: [id])
  fileId Int?

  /* Optional: A single file (image) can be provided as an avatar */
  avatar   File? @relation(fields: [avatarId], references: [id])
  avatarId Int?

  /* A user that have created this event */
  createBy       User @relation(fields: [createByUserId], references: [id])
  createByUserId Int
}

model File {
  id        Int    @id @default(autoincrement())

  /* A user that have uploaded the file */
  uploadedBy       User @relation(fields: [uploadedByUserId], references: [id])
  uploadedByUserId Int

  /* Backwards relations */
  event   Event? @relation(fields: [eventId], references: [id])
  eventId Int?
  user    User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId  Int?
}

model User {
  id     Int     @id @default(autoincrement())

  /* Backwards relation for uploaded files */
  uploadedFiles File[]

  /* Backwards relation for avatar file (image) */
  avatar File?

  /* Backwards relation for event (created by) */
  event Event[]
}
```

For now there is an error, saying:

```
Error validating model "Event": Ambiguous relation detected.
The fields `files` and `avatar` in model `Event` both refer to `File`.
Please provide different relation names for them by adding `@relation(<name>).
```

Can you help me fix these models relations?

Comment: For better readability on stackoverflow, I have replaced inline comments `// ...` to a block comments `/* ... */`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post an answer. I have used Chat GPT to help resolve my problem. May be someone someday will find this helpful.

```sql
model Event {
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())

  /* Backwards relation for attached files to the event [1..M] */
  files File[] @relation("EventFiles")

  /* Relation for the avatar file [1..1] */
  avatar      File?   @relation("EventAvatar", fields: [avatarId], references: [id])
  avatarId    Int?    @unique

  /* A user that has created this event [M..1] */
  createdBy       User @relation(fields: [createdByUserId], references: [id])
  createdByUserId Int
}

model File {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())

  /* A user that has uploaded the file [M..1] */
  uploadedBy       User @relation("Uploader", fields: [uploadedByUserId], references: [id])
  uploadedByUserId Int

  /* Event to which the files is attached to [M..1] */
  event   Event @relation("EventFiles", fields: [eventId], references: [id])
  eventId Int

  /* Backwards relation for event avatar [1..1] */
  eventAvatar Event? @relation("EventAvatar")

  /* Backwards relation for user avatar [1..1] */
  userAvatar User? @relation("UserAvatar")
}

model User {
  id     Int     @id @default(autoincrement())

  /* A user that has uploaded the file [M..1] */
  uploadedBy       User @relation("Uploader", fields: [uploadedByUserId], references: [id])
  uploadedByUserId Int

  /* Event to which the files is attached to [M..1] */
  event   Event @relation("EventFiles", fields: [eventId], references: [id])
  eventId Int

  /* Backwards relation for event avatar [1..1] */
  eventAvatar Event? @relation("EventAvatar")

  /* Backwards relation for user avatar [1..1] */
  userAvatar User? @relation("UserAvatar")
}
```